# jquery .next('input').focus()

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

Passcoder is jquery library that I have made and will be releasing. It splits an input field into one-character input boxes (like the iPhone passcode). One of the features it to focus the next input one you press a button.

The problem seems to be that the `.next('.passcoder')` does not do what is expected. On the first row of inputs (the employee_name inputs) it will behave as expected, but when it is supposed to focus the first of the password inputs (going from the forth employee name to password) the `.next('.passcoder')` does not return anything.

The markup:

```
<form action="" method="post"
    <h4>Employee Number</h4>
        <input type="text" class="single-character-name passcoder" name="employee_number-0">
        <input type="text" class="single-character-name passcoder" name="employee_number-1">
        <input type="text" class="single-character-name passcoder" name="employee_number-2">
        <input type="text" class="single-character-name passcoder" name="employee_number-3">
    <br>
    <h4>Employee Passcode</h4>
        <input type="password" class="single-character-password passcoder" name="employee_passcode-0">
        <input type="password" class="single-character-password passcoder" name="employee_passcode-1">
        <input type="password" class="single-character-password passcoder" name="employee_passcode-2">
        <input type="password" class="single-character-password passcoder" name="employee_passcode-3">
    <br />
    <br />
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
        <a class="btn">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

The javascript (jQuery):

```
$('.passcoder').keyup(function(e){
    if (e.which == 8){
        //backspace
        $(this).prev('input').focus();
    }
    else if(e.which > 47 && e.which < 58){
        $(this).next('.passcoder').focus();
    }
    else{
        $(this).val('');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: $(this).val(''); instead of value()

Comment: sorry, I fixed that in the code after I pasted it here. Sorry about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `prevAll` and `nextAll` with the selector `:first` to find the next and the previous element:

```
$('.passcoder').keyup(function(e){
    if (e.which == 8){
        //backspace
        $(this).prevAll('input:first').focus();
    }
    else if(e.which > 47 && e.which < 58){
        $(this).nextAll('.passcoder:first').focus();
    }
    else{
        $(this).val('');
        return false;
    }
});
```

You can see this working at http://jsfiddle.net/V7SHp/

Comment: Thank you. I had tried `nextAll('.passcoder')`. Correct me if I am wrong, but nextAll returns all the next elements in a list, so the :first selector will return only the first of the list.

Comment: @JacobValenta You are right, only returns the first, in case of the `prev` the first is the closest element.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is using the num pad. Try using your normal numbers, or add keycode 97 to 105 to you `else if` block `(e.which > 47 && e.which < 58) || (e.which > 96 && e.which < 106)`

```
$('.passcoder').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 8) {
        //backspace
        $(this).prev('input').focus();
    } else if ((e.which > 47 && e.which < 58) || (e.which > 96 && e.which < 106)) {
        $(this).next('.passcoder').focus();
    } else {
        $(this).value('');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Try the fiddle. It doesnt work. it works for the first 3 inputs, but it will not change from the 4th to the 5th

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(this).nextAll(".passcoder").eq(0).focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the `jQuery.next` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next
>   sibling only if it matches that selector.

Since you have a `<br>` and a `<h4>` between your `input`, the `next` method does not return the input.

Comment: Check the arg you pass to .next() it lets you filter it. I put '.passcoder' so it should find the next element with a class of passcoder

Comment: If I understand well what the docs state, when you pass an arg to `next` it retrieves the immediately following sibling (in this case, the <br>) only if it matches that selector (in this case, it does not, so it isn't returning nothing).

Comment: Ah, thanks! That seems a little confusing, as .next seems like a 'get' and not an 'if' kind of function.

Comment: @JacobValenta +1, it's even more confusing if you are used to prototypeJS, which has also a `next` method but behaves more intuitive IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/DDNbQ/

```
var next = $(this).next('.passcoder');
if (next.length>0) {
    next.focus();
} else {
    $(this).nextUntil('.passcoder').next('.passcoder').focus();
}
```